# It's possible to ignore a ServiceFilter controller for one action only?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

It's possible to ignore a ServiceFilter controller for one action only and applicate another servicefilter? In my case for the action "MethodTwo"

```
[Route("api/test")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(RequireFilter1))]
public class TestController : BaseApiController
{
  public ActionResult MethodOne()
  {
    //Code
  }

  [ServiceFilter(typeof(RequireFilter2))]
  public ActionResult MethodTwo(int id)
  {
     //Code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hello**.

For your case, both filters will be executed in MethodTwo.

Here you can read more about filters execute sequence - [Filters in ASP.NET Core - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

So for your case you can analyze existing action attributes in RequireFilter1 and do not execute it in case if any other ServiceFilterAttribute is assigned to action. 
Or you can create your attribute which will block Controller attribute.

For example (disable controller filter execution if ServiceFilterAttribute attached to action):

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var actDescr = (context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor);
        if (actDescr!=null)
        {
            var attrs = actDescr.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ServiceFilterAttribute),true);
            if (attrs.Any())
                return;
        }
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("ActionFilterExample1",
                                             new string[] { "test ActionFilterExample1", "test ActionFilterExample0" });
    }
```

Also, you must do the same for **OnActionExecuted** of the filter.

Another way - create separate attribute for disabling controller attribute:

```
public class DisableAttr : Attribute  
{

}
```

And check it in OnActionExecuting :

```
actDescr.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisableAttr),true);
```